# How do I split text into multiple fields using Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, dimensional-modeling

I have a table with a column that needs to be split and inserted into a new table. Column's name is `location` and has data that could look like `Detroit, MI, USA;Chicago, IL, USA` or as simple as `USA`.

Ultimately, I want to insert the data into a new dimension table that looks like:

```
City   | State | Country|
Detroit  MI      USA
Chicago  IL      USA
NULL     NULL    USA
```

I came across the `string_to_array` function and am able to split the larger example (`Detroit, MI, USA; Chicago, IL, USA)` into 2 strings of `Detroit, MI, USA` and `Chicago, IL, USA`.

Now I'm  stumped on how to split those strings again and then insert them. Since there are two strings separated by a comma, does using `string_to_array` again work? It doesn't seem to work in Sqlfiddle.

Note: I'm using Sqlfiddle right now since I don't have access to my Redshift table at the moment.

This is for Redshift, which unfortunately is still using PostGresql 8.0.2 and thus does not have the `unnest` function

Answer (score 2):

```
postgres=# select v[1] as city, v[1] as state, v[2] as country
              from (select string_to_array(unnest(string_to_array(
           'Detroit, MI, USA;Chicago, IL, USA',';')),',')) s(v);
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│  city   │  state  │ country │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ Detroit │ Detroit │  MI     │
│ Chicago │ Chicago │  IL     │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
(2 rows)
```

Tested on Postgres, not sure if it will work on Redshift too

Next query should to work on every Postgres

```
select  v[1] as city, v[1] as state, v[2] as country 
    from (select string_to_array(v, ',') v 
             from unnest(string_to_array(
'Detroit, MI, USA;Chicago, IL, USA',';')) g(v)) s;
```

It use old PostgreSQL trick - using derived table.

```
SELECT v[1], v[2] FROM (SELECT string_to_array('1,2',',')) g(v)
```

Unnest function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _unnest(anyarray)
RETURNS SETOF anyelement AS '
BEGIN
  FOR i IN array_lower($1,1) .. array_upper($1,1) LOOP
    RETURN NEXT $1[i];
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I don't think this will solve the problem, given the example of a first-level array which contains only a country code such as USA.

Comment: Just realized that Redshift is based on Postgres 8.0... Completely thought it was 9.0. Do you know of an alternative to `unnest`?

Comment: @RonDunn actually, the data might be standardized into 3-level arrays for all entries

Comment: @simplycoding see updated text - there is source code for `unnest`. 8.0 is pretty old, but I hope it should to work.

Comment: Hey @Pavel I'm trying to go through the `unnest` function you wrote up. It doesn't seem to work when I just do a copy+paste+execute. I'm getting an error of "uneterminated dollar-quoted string at or near `"$$ BEGIN
  FOR i IN array_lower($1,1) .. array_upper($1,1) LOOP
    RETURN NEXT $1[i]`

Comment: @simplycoding hmm .. rechecked  and it is working. Try to use one apostrophe "'"instead $$

Comment: Thanks. Turns out Redshift doesn't even support creating functions, unless it's with Python... Ugh.